# Loop through checkboxes in listview control to Update Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

Below is my ASP.net code with my Listview Control with a checkbox `absentCheckBox`

```
<asp:ListView ID="student_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="view_students">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <tr style="">
    <td>
     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("assignment_id") %>' runat="server" ID="assignment_idLabel" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' runat="server" ID="user_idLabel" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("result_percentage") %>' runat="server" ID="result_percentageTextBox" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <asp:CheckBox Checked='<%# Eval("absent") %>' runat="server" ID="absentCheckBox" />
    </td>
   </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="add_results" runat="server" Text="Update Results" OnClick="add_results_Click" CssClass="blue" />
```

Below is my C# code behind where I am trying to loop through the checkboxes in

```
protected void add_results_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in student_list.Items)
        {
            int student_id = 0;
            Label student_id_lbl = (Label)item.FindControl("user_idLabel");
            student_id = Convert.ToInt32(student_id_lbl.Text);

            int assignment_id = 0;
            Label assignment_id_lbl = (Label)item.FindControl("assignment_idLabel");
            assignment_id = Convert.ToInt32(assignment_id_lbl.Text);

            int result = 0;
            TextBox result_total_ddl = item.FindControl("result_percentageTextBox") as TextBox;
            if (result_total_ddl != null)
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(result_total_ddl.Text, out result))
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }

            bool absent = false;
            CheckBox absent_chk = item.FindControl("absentCheckBox") as CheckBox;
            absent = Convert.ToBoolean(absent_chk.Text);

            if (result < 0 || result > 100)
            {
                feedback.Text = "Please enter an assignment total in between 0 - 100 you have entered : <b>" + result + "</b>.";
            }
            else
            {
                String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                myConnection.Open();

                String query = "UPDATE assignments_vs_users SET result_percentage = @result_percentage, absent = @absent WHERE assignment_id = @assignment_id AND user_id = @student_id; ";

                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result_percentage", result);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assignment_id", assignment_id);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", student_id);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@absent", absent);

                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I use `absent` within `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@absent", absent);` so it updates the database column for absent if the checkbox is ticked to `true`

Comment: Where is the code that updates the db?

Comment: @Steve I updated my question with all my code, including the code that updates the DB

Comment: Your checkbox has no text value. Therefore it's grabbing a null value. change it to absent = absent_chk.Checked;

Comment: @Kramb Thank you! That worked, I was unsure how to grab the value. Thanks again.